# Running .NET 2.0 apps with an IIS ASP.NET version of 4.0

Tags: iis-6, version, asp.net-2.0, virtual-directory

We have a bunch of ASP.NET apps written in .NET 2.0 (with IIS6 ASP.NET version set to 2.0), visible via Virtual Directories within one website deployed to Windows Server 2003.  Does anyone know whether we can set the ASP.NET version within IIS, of all of these to 4.0 without breaking the (.NET 2.0) applications - i.e. no other changes other than within IIS

Any official Microsoft link(s) stating this can be done, would be brilliant also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid such "big changes". ASP.NET 1.x, 2.0 and 4.0 applications should be separated and held in standalone application pools.

Besides, there are too many breaking changes in ASP.NET 4 compared to previous versions, you should carefully migrate when the time is right,

http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes